# Paypal integration in laravel giving error on get payment status (although transaction becomes successful)

Tags: php, laravel, api, paypal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSv1a.jpg)

This the code I am using for getting the status of the transaction....client ID and secret are the same and the transaction is successful from the PayPal dashboard and all variables used in this function not empty and these are accurate

```
 $paymentId  = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
 /** clear the session payment ID **/
 Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
 $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $this->_api_context);
 $execution = new PaymentExecution();
 $payer_id=$request->input('PayerID');
 $execution->setPayerId($payer_id);
  $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
 if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
 \Session::put('success', 'Payment success');
             return Redirect::route('success');
 }
 \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
         return Redirect::route('failed');
```

Comment: looks like ``` Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
 $payment = Payment::get(Session::get('paypal_payment_id'), $this->_api_context);``` is backwards. Youre forgetting it, then trying to get it. Remove the session:forget() and try again.

Comment: i have replace variable but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
$paymentId  = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
$payment = Payment::get(Session::get('paypal_payment_id').....
```

Since you are forgetting your session variable, the last line should be

```
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId.....
```

---

Other possible causes of the `AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE` response in the image include:

1. Missing or invalid api_context
2. api_context with missing ClientID and Secret
3. api_context with wrong ClientID and secret
4. Wrong environment configured or Client ID and secret for wrong environment (sandbox vs. live/production modes)
5. A problem with the particular Client ID and secret you are using (generate a new [sandbox account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F) , followed by a new [sandbox app](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/) for it)

If you still have issues after all that, test with another tool such as curl or Postman and:

- If that works try to debug your full request and response including headers to see what you are doing wrong
- If another tool also doesn't work, contact PayPal for support

Comment: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-L6FLOBY7VD17593NG571403H/execute.
Getting same error after creating new sandbox account...
I am also using postman but unable to fix till now

Comment: A `400` or a 401? Those are different situations. If it's a 400 check your request as there's a problem with it, and if possible log the full request and response

Comment: Also I don't understand why you're wasting time integrating the old v1/payments API with the deprecated PayPal-PHP-SDK.  Use the new v2/checkout/orders with the current Checkout-PHP/SDK, as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ .  You need two new server routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', which you can then pair with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Now i am using srmklive plugin but i am getting this 

Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout' not found
I have published all services